# Global assignment using purrr functions

Tags: r, iteration, purrr

How do you replace a for loop with purrr functions? There are a lot of cases that are [straightforward](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#the-map-functions), but in this case, I am trying to do an assignment during the loop. Lexical scoping is used to find the object to modify, but it does not save the progress. It's as if the modification only happens at each iteration and then it's dropped.

The result should be updated matrices `dead_yes` and `dead_no`.

Edited to use pwalk() to emphasize side effects instead of output based on @hadley's comment. We do not want anything returned; instead, we are just modifying an existing variable.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(faraway)
data(femsmoke)

dead_yes <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(femsmoke$smoker)), ncol = length(unique(femsmoke$age)))
dead_no <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(femsmoke$smoker)), ncol = length(unique(femsmoke$age)))

colnames(dead_yes) <- colnames(dead_no) <- unique(femsmoke$age)
rownames(dead_yes) <- rownames(dead_no) <- unique(femsmoke$smoker)

w <- unique(femsmoke$age)
v <- unique(femsmoke$smoker)
u <- unique(femsmoke$dead)

pwalk(list(
  row = match(femsmoke$smoker, v),
  col = match(femsmoke$age, w),
  y = femsmoke$y,
  dead = femsmoke$dead
), function(row, col, y, dead) {
  if (dead == "yes") {
    dead_yes[row, col] <- y
  } else {
    dead_no[row, col] <- y
  }
})
```

Created on 2018-09-29 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Are you trying to get counts (held in the y variable)  of dead="yes" within categories of smoker and age status? If so, I would think you could use `xtabs`.

Comment: Yes. I have already done it a different way. So the answer isn't so important. Now I am more interested in how to do the assignment using map functions.

Comment: xtabs does work perfectly by the way. Thank you for sharing, but I still want to figure out how to do assignment within map function, if it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to alter the `x` object in the global environment, you
need to use `<<-` for assignment inside the iterative machine (for
`[lv]apply()` or `purrr::map()`). Generic example:

```r
(x <- rep(NA_integer_, 3))
#> [1] NA NA NA

purrr::map_dbl(1:3, function(i) x[[i]] <- -i)
#> [1] -1 -2 -3
x
#> [1] NA NA NA

vapply(1:3, function(i) x[[i]] <- -i, integer(1))
#> [1] -1 -2 -3
x
#> [1] NA NA NA

purrr::map_dbl(1:3, function(i) x[[i]] <<- -i)
#> [1] -1 -2 -3
x
#> [1] -1 -2 -3

vapply(1:3, function(i) x[[i]] <<- -2L * i, integer(1))
#> [1] -2 -4 -6
x
#> [1] -2 -4 -6
```

Modifying an object in a parent environment really goes against the
functional nature of of these functions, though. In general, when you have to use `<<-`, it often means there’s another approach to the problem. In this case, it seems like data reshaping would be another way to think of the original task.

But, to answer the original question, using `<<-` makes the original
code ‘work’. I switched to `purrr::pwalk()` to emphasize the side effects and also converted `dead` from factor to character.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(faraway)
data(femsmoke)

dead_yes <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(femsmoke$smoker)), ncol = length(unique(femsmoke$age)))
dead_no <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(femsmoke$smoker)), ncol = length(unique(femsmoke$age)))

colnames(dead_yes) <- colnames(dead_no) <- unique(femsmoke$age)
rownames(dead_yes) <- rownames(dead_no) <- unique(femsmoke$smoker)

w <- unique(femsmoke$age)
v <- unique(femsmoke$smoker)
u <- unique(femsmoke$dead)

pwalk(list(
  row = match(femsmoke$smoker, v),
  col = match(femsmoke$age, w),
  y = femsmoke$y,
  dead = as.character(femsmoke$dead)
), function(row, col, y, dead) {
  if (dead == "yes") {
    dead_yes[row, col] <<- y
  } else {
    dead_no[row, col] <<- y
  }
})
dead_yes
#>     18-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64 65-74 75+
#> yes     2     3    14    27    51    29  13
#> no      1     5     7    12    40   101  64
dead_no
#>     18-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64 65-74 75+
#> yes    53   121    95   103    64     7   0
#> no     61   152   114    66    81    28   0
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Funny. As you did this, I remembered the same solution and ended up using it. I agree there are better methods (global assignment is dangerous, and I would not use in practice) higher up the abstract ladder, such as xtabs. I originally took the approach of replicating the rows by the `y` column then reshaping with the full data. That worked fine, but I wanted to try another. 

What I am curious about, programmatically, why does lexical scope work for `for loops`, but not map functions? Why can you assign up the environment chain implicitly with the former and not the latter?

Comment: I've heard people make a distinction between "control structures" like `for(){}` , `while(){}`, `repeat{}`, and `if(){}else{}` which support assignments in the global environment and "ordinary functions" whose assignments are limited to their local environment. Notice that `for`, `while`, and `repeat` all return NULL as their value, a common source of confusion for new R users.

Comment: I think you should use `pwalk()` here to emphasise that it’s about the side effects.

Comment: @42 control flow structures don’t create new ecnvitonments in R; functions do.

Comment: I'll research control structures. I think you may have covered in Advanced R? @hadley. I also added `pwalk()` afterward on my local machine. I'll update the post to highlight the side effects point you made @hadley.

Comment: @hadley. I think that's what I said or at least was trying to say.

Comment: There can be confusion if you run `is.function` against `for`.

Comment: @42- Thanks for your insight.